# Launchpad Release file missing

Tags: release-management

When I started Software Updater in 18.04 this error occurred but the update went on and completed

E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/sbackup-team/stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

Being a retired end user do I need to fix the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Please read your link http://ppa.launchpad.net/sbackup-team/stable/ubuntu/dists/ ... to know that the files are for Ubuntu 14.04 or earlier.